# unable to search 2G(EDGE) network

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, mobile-broadband

i am using huawei e1732 data card. in windows every thing is fine. now i am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. And i am not able to use any 2G network. please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether your device is listed by the output  of `lsusb`
- Use `nm-connection-editor` to set up your network
- Try to connect

If this does not work for you, report the problems / error messages.

Comment: thank you for reply me class. with your advice ihave checked the output of lsub and it shows my device. my problem is that my devicel does not detect any 2G(EDGE) network. if 3G is available than its ok. so can you help me to solve this problem.